# How to customize object-motions?

Tags: object-motions

[Text object motions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-motions) are useful to move around in a file. Although these motion commands were specifically created for text (novel) writers, they can also be used in C source code.

The commands `gd` and `gD` make use of object-motions and I find them very helpful when working with C, but as far as I can tell there is no way of making it work for languages that do not use brackets.

I can see that it is possible to workaround this by remapping all these commands (example [here](https://github.com/edkolev/erlang-motions.vim/blob/master/after/ftplugin/erlang.vim)).

But is there a way of configuring object-motions for languages that do not make use of brackets, such that the command `gd` would be able to quickly find local variable definitions without having to remap it to a custom function?

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to generate tags for a project and then use them to navigate your code?

Comment: I would have to use `:tselect` or `g]` and *then* selecting one of the many possibilities. Imagine if the variable is called `i` ;) And you should really be advising Universal Ctags, which at least is being actively supported.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to make sure that you were aware that this kind of solution existed :)

Comment: With vim, you can customize `gd` or `gD` per filetype, to use custom searches instead of `{`. If that helps. The specific example is missing ;) Python example (just searched for it): https://github.com/danielroseman/pygd-vim

Comment: @VanLaser you answered the question with an example. You should post it as an actual answer.

Comment: @jecxjo - actually, I'm not sure what the author exactly wants (what's his specific case, language etc. - or it's just a theoretical question?); also I don't like to post *that* example (it's a plugin made in Python, pretty convoluted), and I don't have an example made by me (since I didn't feel the need to customize `gd` or `gD`). :)

Comment: I was really looking for a native configuration to achieve this. Reviewed question text to clarify this.